# Should `stripe.confirmCardPayment` emit `incorrect_cvc` error code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

Given I have the following stripe client side code inside of a react component:

```
const stripeResponse = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
          type: 'card',
          card: elements.getElement('cardNumber'),
          billing_details: {
            address: {
              city: selectedAddress.town,
              country: selectedAddress.country.iso3166Code,
              line1: selectedAddress.line1,
              line2: selectedAddress.line2,
              postal_code: selectedAddress.postalCode,
              state: selectedAddress.region,
            },
            email: "some_email@mail.com",
            name: "form_field_name",
            phone: selectedAddress.phone,
          },
        });

        if (stripeResponse.error) {
          console.log("Should we be able to get Error Codes and Decline Codes?") 
        }
```

Does `stripe.createPaymentMethod` allow to see decline and error codes that are mentioned in the documentation? For instance, I am not seeing error code `incorrect_cvc` for card number `4000000000000127`

Reference:
https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=card-numbers#declined-payments

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These errors are not surfaced when calling `createPaymentMethod` in Stripe.js. You will encounter these errors when you try to [attach that payment method to a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach), or use it to [confirm a PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent-payment_method) (or SetupIntent).

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods/pm_card_chargeDeclinedIncorrectCvc/attach \
  -u sk_test_123: \
  --data customer=cus_456
```